# Efficiently Update List of dicts by comparison

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have two list of dicts,

Say,

```
required = [
  {"name": "a", "req_Key": "a"},
  {"name": "b", "req_Key": "b"},
  {"name": "c", "req_Key": "c"},
  {"name": "d", "req_Key": "d"}
]

updated = [
  {"name": "a", "output_id": "Oa"},
  {"name": "d", "output_id": "Od"}
]
```

Now I need to update `required` dicts by comparing with `updated` dicts,

So the output will look like

```
[
  {'req_Key': 'a', 'name': 'a', 'output_id': 'Oa'},
  {'req_Key': 'b', 'name': 'b'},
  {'req_Key': 'c', 'name': 'c'},
  {'req_Key': 'd', 'name': 'd', 'output_id': 'Od'}
]
```

I am using loops to do this, but how can I do this efficiently by avoiding loops?

Sample Code:

```
required = [{"name":"a","req_Key":"a"},{"name":"b","req_Key":"b"},{"name":"c","req_Key":"c"},{"name":"d","req_Key":"d"}]

updated = [{"name":"a","output_id":"Oa"},{"name":"d","output_id":"Od"}]

for updated_record in updated:

    for req_record in required:
        if updated_record["name"] == req_record["name"]:
            req_record.update(updated_record)
            print(req_record)
```

Its working, but I need better and efficient method.

Comment: is `name` key unique between records?

Comment: yes it should be unique..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transform your update data first, so you can get constant lookup times:

```
update_data = {d['name']: d for d in update}

for d in required:
    d.update(update_data.get(d['name'], {}))
```

This assumes that `name` is unique in your update data. Otherwise, you can do:

```
from collections import defaultdict

update_data = defaultdict(dict)
for d in update:
    update_data[d['name']].update(d)

for d in required:
    d.update(update_data.get(d['name'], {}))
```

These approaches both iterate each list only once `(O(N+M))` which is a significant improvement over the nested lists approach `(O(M*N))`.

Answer (score 0):

This is one approach.

```
required = [{"name":"a","req_Key":"a"},{"name":"b","req_Key":"b"},{"name":"c","req_Key":"c"},{"name":"d","req_Key":"d"}]
updated = [{"name":"a","output_id":"Oa"},{"name":"d","output_id":"Od"}]

updated = dict((i["name"], i["output_id"]) for i in updated)

for i in required:
    i.update({'output_id': updated.get(i["name"])})
print(required)
```

**Output:**

```
[{'output_id': 'Oa', 'req_Key': 'a', 'name': 'a'}, {'output_id': None, 'req_Key': 'b', 'name': 'b'}, {'output_id': None, 'req_Key': 'c', 'name': 'c'}, {'output_id': 'Od', 'req_Key': 'd', 'name': 'd'}]
```

Comment: Please can you elaborate a little